# How to modify a code with composition operator?

Tags: ocaml

I would like to slightly modify the following functions of [this code](https://github.com/yurug/menhir-error-recovery):

```ml
let find_context = function
  | InputNeeded env ->
     pop_until element_contains_prediction_items env
     (* (pop_until element_contains_prediction_items env, current_state_number env) *)
  | _ ->
     assert false

... ...

let contextual_error_msg lexer checkpoint continuation =
  find_context checkpoint |> fun nonterminals ->
  Error.error "parsing" (Lexer.current_position lexer)
     (Printf.sprintf "Error while analyzing %s."
    (String.concat " or " (List.map Symbol.string_of_symbol nonterminals)))
  @@ continuation
```

```ml
let resume_on_error last_reduction lex =
(* let resume_on_error last_reduction lex currentStateNumber = *)
  match last_reduction with

... ...

  let rec on_error last_reduction lexer checkpoint =
    contextual_error_msg lexer checkpoint (fun () ->
      resume_on_error last_reduction lexer
    )
```

I plan to make `find_context` to return the current state number as well (the expected code is commented above), and make this current state number to be finally passed to `resume_on_error` (the expected code is commented above).

But I have difficulty in modifying `contextual_error_msg` and `on_error`; it is `continuation` that makes things complicated; and I don't know what's the purpose of using `@@` here.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the operator precedence here : https://ocaml.org/api/Ocaml_operators.html
[image]
`@@` has priority over `|>`

Here is an example :

```ml
utop # let foo = 3. |> fun x y -> x +. 2.*.y  @@ 1.;;
Error: This expression has type float but an expression was expected of type
         'a -> 'b
─( 14:42:53 )─< command 11 >─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────{ counter: 0 }─
utop # let bar = 3. |> fun x y -> x +. 2.*.y  1.;;
- : (float -> float) -> float = <fun>
```

`foo` is interpreted as

```ml
(fun x y -> (x +. 2. *. y ) 1.) 3.
```

and `bar` as

```ml
(fun x y -> x +. 2 *. (y 1.)) 3.
```

which is

```ml
fun y -> 3 +. 2 *. y 1.
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you think `foo` is interpreted as `(fun x y -> x +. ((2. *. y) 1.)) 3.` or `(fun x y -> (x +. 2. *. y) 1.) 3.`?

Comment: I checked the doc and edited my answer, it's actually the second solution